# What does $P(dx|H)$ stand for in probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, notation, expectation, conditional-expectation

In the [Conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) Wikipedia page, in the [Classical definition: Conditional expectation with respect to an event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event) section, there is a $P(dx | H)$ notation, whose meaning I don't understand:

---

[image]

---

According to the explanation below it should be $P(dx\cap H)/P(H)$, but the $dx$ part is still confusing.

**What I want** is a very clear, purely real analysis notation, i.e., one that specifies the domain over which to integrate, the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra, the measure and the integrand function, instead of the sorta elusive probabilistic formulation. It seems the integral domain is $\mathcal X$, but neither the $\sigma$-algebra nor the measure is readily apparent to me. Any help?

Comment: Sorry for the blurred image. I always have this problem uploading images on my iPhone. This can't be helped.

Comment: Its a Radon Nykodym derivative.

Comment: $E(X|H) = \int_X x f_{X|H}(x) dx$ where $f_{X|H}(x)$ is the pdf of $X | H$ and since $f_{X|H}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[ P(X \le x|H)]$ you have $f_{X|H}(x) dx = d [P(X \le x|H)] $, and $P(dx | H)$ would be a short hand for that

Comment: @user1952009 well, thanks. But I'm still *struggling* with the basic concept of conditional expectation. Could you explain without it?

Comment: Just define the random variable $Y \sim \ \ X | (H = h)$, such that $P(Y \le x) = P(X \le x | H = h)$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff oh my....

Comment: @PedroTamaroff so it is impossible to reduce it into simple formulation like $$\int_X f\mathrm d\mu$$?

Comment: Yes, $E(Y) = \int_Y y \ d[P(Y \le y)]$ so if $Y =    \ \ X| H$ then $E(X| H) =  \int_X x \  d[P(X \le x | H)]$, it doesn't say anything else

Comment: @Vim It depends. If $Y$ has a distribution, then you can do so: if $\mu$ is a measure of the form $\int f d\lambda$ for some other measure $\lambda$, then $d\mu/d\lambda$ is $f$.

Comment: @user1952009 I think the integral domain should be $\Omega$, the underlying sample domain, but not $X$ or $Y$. They are just functions, not domains. However this doesn't seem to agree with the $\int_{x\in\mathcal X}$ notation on that page. Anyway could you please specify your integral domain and $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The $\int_{x \in X}$ notation is weird (as the $P(dx | H)$ one)

Comment: The notation is an abomination indeed, confusing measures on the source space $\Omega$ and on the image space $\mathbb R$. Correct formulas would be $$E(X\mid H)=\int_\Omega X(\omega)P(d\omega\mid H)$$ or $$E(X\mid H)=\int_\mathbb R x\mu_H(dx)$$ where $\mu_H$ would be the distribution of $X$ conditionallly on $H$, that is, a measure on $\mathbb R$. Since this conditional distribution would have to be defined carefully, I am not sure the WP formula explains anything at all.

Comment: @user1952009 There is no conditioning by $H=h$ involved here, $H$ is an event and not a random variable.

Comment: @Did are the two definitions you provide equivalent? I think the first is in the spirit of the Riemann integral (working on the domain) while the second the Lebesgue integral (the range).

Comment: Both are Lebesgue. Yes the integral on $\Omega$ is on $\Omega$ and the integral on $\mathbb R$ is on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Did I know both are Lebesgue. But are they the same? I mean, since $X:\Omega\to \Bbb R$ is a r.v., it feels like the first is using Riemann's *idea*, integrating over the domain, while the latter uses Lebesgue's notion, over the range.

Comment: Yes they are the same, this is a theorem (often called "transfer theorem") explained when one introduces the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit in that explanation is 1) some state space $(\cal{X},\mathscr{X})$ in which $X$ takes values, and 2) that $P(\cdot\mid H)=P(\cdot,H)$ is a probability measure on $(\cal{X},\mathscr{X})$. The existence of a $P(\cdot,H)$ satisfying 2) and also satisfying the relation mentioned toward the end of the screenshot $P(A,H)=P(A|H)=P(A\cap H)/P(H)$ (also implicit is $A\in\mathscr{X}$) amounts to the existence of a regular conditional probability distribution for $X$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, which will hold, e.g., when $X$ is real-valued. As pointed out in the comment below, when we pass to the more everyday bayesian formula definition of event $A$ conditional on event $B$ we actually want to write $P(X^{-1}(A)\cap H)/P(H)$

"What I want is a very clear, purely real analysis notation, i.e., one that specifies the domain over which to integrate," --> $\cal X$

the corresponding σσ-algebra, --> $\mathscr X$

the measure --> $P(\cdot,H)$

and the integrand function" --> the identity

Maybe some of the confusion is also due to the notation of the integrator $P(dx,H)$. This just means integrate with dummy variable $x$ using the measure $P(\cdot,H)$, e.g., for lebesgue measure I might write $\int_0^\pi cos(x)\lambda(dx)$ for $\int_0^\pi cos(x)dx$.

Another possible point of confusion: using the same letter $P$ to refer to the underlying measure on the probability space $(\Omega,\cal{F},P)$ and the rcpd $P(\cdot | \cdot)$.

Comment: If $P(\ , H)$ is a measure on $\mathcal X$, then $P(A,H)=P(A\cap H)/P(H)$ is absurd since $A$ should be a subset of the source space $\Omega$ for $P(A\cap H)$ to make sense. (Not your fault, the absurdity is in the WP text.)

Comment: @Did yeah, like the wikipedia article I muddle in my head the pushforward with the main probability. I will clarify shortly.

Comment: Your edit misses the point, please refer to my first comment (or to my comment on main). As a result, this post is (still) misleading.

Comment: @Did I interpret your comment to be that it is absurd to intersect subsets of different spaces, so I write $P(A,H)=P(X^{-1}(A)\cap H)/P(H)$ to avoid that absurdity. What remains misleading?

Comment: The part "when we pass to the more everyday bayesian formula definition of event A conditional on event B" refers to nothing I can understand. The mention of "the existence of a regular conditional probability distribution for X" is offtopic as well. Recall that H is just an event (with positive probability), not a sigma-algebra.

Comment: By passing to the bayes formula definition I refer to the equality we have been talking about, "P(A|H)=P(A\cap H)/P(H)". I think the easiest way to reconcile this definition to the integral equation that was confusing the OP is through the rcpd, since the integral equation is against the measure $dP(\cdot,H)$. I don't see why $H$ being an event is an issue, it's still an RV and that RV still has a (small) $\sigma$-algebra.